# Why the same js code works on div but does not work on canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to tweak this demo to work on canvas:
http://soulwire.github.io/sketch.js/examples/particles.html

The demo code is only an html file with a div element in it and two js file. It achieves particle effects.

Originally, the demo sets container to a div element and it works.

I modified the html file change the div to a canvas element and set the container to canvas. Then it stops working.

I have little clue where to look at to find the cause.

This is the html file that works:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>particles</title>
    <script src="sketch.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="frame"></div>
    <script src="particles.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the particle JS code:

```
    // ----------------------------------------
    // Particle
    // ----------------------------------------

    function Particle( x, y, radius ) {
        this.init( x, y, radius );
    }

    Particle.prototype = {

        init: function( x, y, radius ) {

            this.alive = true;

            this.radius = radius || 10;
            this.wander = 0.15;
            this.theta = random( TWO_PI );
            this.drag = 0.92;
            this.color = '#fff';

            this.x = x || 0.0;
            this.y = y || 0.0;

            this.vx = 0.0;
            this.vy = 0.0;
        },

        move: function() {

            this.x += this.vx;
            this.y += this.vy;

            this.vx *= this.drag;
            this.vy *= this.drag;

            this.theta += random( -0.5, 0.5 ) * this.wander;
            this.vx += sin( this.theta ) * 0.1;
            this.vy += cos( this.theta ) * 0.1;

            this.radius *= 0.96;
            this.alive = this.radius > 0.5;
        },

        draw: function( ctx ) {

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc( this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, TWO_PI );
            ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
            ctx.fill();
        }
    };

    // ----------------------------------------
    // Example
    // ----------------------------------------

    var MAX_PARTICLES = 280;
    var COLOURS = [ '#69D2E7', '#A7DBD8', '#E0E4CC', '#F38630', '#FA6900', '#FF4E50', '#F9D423' ];

    var particles = [];
    var pool = [];

    var demo = Sketch.create({
        container: document.getElementById( 'frame' )
    });

    demo.setup = function() {

        // Set off some initial particles.
        var i, x, y;

        for ( i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {
            x = ( demo.width * 0.01 ) + random( -10, 10 );
            y = ( demo.height * 0.01 ) + random( -10, 10 );
            demo.spawn( x, y );
        }
    };

    demo.spawn = function( x, y ) {

        if ( particles.length >= MAX_PARTICLES )
            pool.push( particles.shift() );

        particle = pool.length ? pool.pop() : new Particle();
        particle.init( x, y, random( 5, 40 ) );

        particle.wander = random( 0.5, 2.0 );
        particle.color = random( COLOURS );
        particle.drag = random( 0.9, 0.99 );

        theta = random( TWO_PI );
        force = random( 2, 8 );

        particle.vx = sin( theta ) * force;
        particle.vy = cos( theta ) * force;

        particles.push( particle );
    };

    demo.update = function() {

        var i, particle;

        for ( i = particles.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {

            particle = particles[i];

            if ( particle.alive ) particle.move();
            else pool.push( particles.splice( i, 1 )[0] );
        }
    };

    demo.draw = function() {

        demo.globalCompositeOperation  = 'lighter';

        for ( var i = particles.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
            particles[i].draw( demo );
        }
    };

    demo.mousemove = function() {

        var particle, theta, force, touch, max, i, j, n;

        for ( i = 0, n = demo.touches.length; i < n; i++ ) {

            touch = demo.touches[i], max = random( 1, 4 );
            for ( j = 0; j < max; j++ ) {
              demo.spawn( touch.x, touch.y );
            }

        }
    };
```

If I create a canvas within the div element, and change the "container" in the JS file from div to the newly-created canvas, it will not work.

Comment: Hi I just added the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sketch (the underlying framework used in the example) adds a canvas inside the container. A canvas can not have child elements, and as such your code fails to work.

Comment: I need to use canvas to draw other things. And I still want to have the particle effect. Do you know how to achieve this? (Render all of them on one canvas.) Or, how to capture the canvas that is created by Sketch.js?

Comment: Yes. You can get the canvas inside the container using e.g. jQuery or vanilla Javascript. For jQuery it would be ``var $canvas = $('.container canvas')``.

Answer (score 1):

In sketch.js

```
element = options.element = options.element || doc.createElement( options.type === DOM ? 'div' : 'canvas' );
```

it checks for the dom type and creates a canvas and all the features act on it also as onberg said the elements inside the canvas wont be visible unless the browser doesnt support canvas.